# How to create multiple form with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, laravel

I want to create multiple form insert data with jquery. i using Laravel for backend, but i got 2 trouble. 
 
First :
how to give name for each input type.
Second :
how to create maximum size in type number when i set the value. in my code you will see (<<<---) sign like this, it's mean how can i put data on console to type number.

here's my code :

```
for(var i = 0;i<jmlitem;i++){
u="<select class='form-control' name='id_item["+i+"]'><option value='0'>--PILIH--</option>"+response+"</select>";
  $('.form-item').append("<div class='form-inline'>"+u+" - "+
                        "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='price["+i+"]' placeholder='price'/>"+ " - " +
                        "<input type='number' class='form-control stock' placeholder='total' min='0' name='jml["+i+"]'/>"+ " - " +    <<<--- add attribut max with value on console.log(data.total) here
                        "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='ket["+i+"]' placeholder='Keterangan'/></div>");
  $("select").change(function(){

     var id_item = $(this).find( "option:selected" ).val();
     var index = $(this).find( "option:selected" ).index();
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "{{URL::to('getharga')}}",
        data: 'id_item='+id_item,
        context:this,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            $(this).next("input[type='text']").val(data.price);
            $("[name='jml["+i+"]']").val(data.total);
            console.log(data.total);  <<<---- value
        }
     });                                               
  });
}
```

can anyone help me ?